# Get this Join query result with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get an Queryable

```
    var result = _context.Product
                .Include(a => a.ProductCategory)
                .AsQueryable();
```

to produce the results of this query using EF Core.

```
SELECT Prod.ProductId,
Prod.ProductName,
Prod.ProductCategoryId,
ISNULL(SUM(Inv.Quantity), 0) AS 'Qty'
FROM PRODUCTS Prod
LEFT JOIN InventoryProductDetails Inv ON Inv.ProductId = Prod.ProductId 
WHERE Prod.Active = 'true'
GROUP BY Prod.ProductId,Prod.ProductName,Prod.ProductCategoryId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_context.Product.Where(p => p.Active)
    .GroupJoin(_context.InventoryProductDetails, 
        p => p.ProductId, inv => inv.ProductId, 
        (p, invs) => new {
            p.ProductId,
            p.ProductName
            p.ProductCategoryId,
            Qty = invs.Sum(i => i.Quantity)
        })
```